# Artifactory is not listing artifacts on web page

Tags: artifactory

I have Jfrog Artifactory 6.11.1 using derby database and we have 94k artifacts are inside and now i am not able to see the those artifacts and when i go backend and check and filestore are very much there about 18GB data.

Please assist me to locate or update which files or properties or xml , look at and get back 94k artifacts back on  Artifactory web page

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have filters on the tree view?

If so, you can un-filter by clicking on the top-right filter button. If you have any filter on package types or repository types, you can remove it by click on the 'X'.

Comment: Data / filestore has 18GB data and still none of artifacts are visible. How to change the defaulft storage ( derby) from /var/opt/jrfrog/artifactory  to /mnt/artifactory/data

Comment: issue with master.key , how to recover or reset the master.key to view all existing artifacts on Artifactory web page